# are there any memory leaks in this code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory

I have successfully created a UITableView/UITableViewCell that is able to slide up and down and adjusting the height to show options. To see what this means, I have created a video [here](http://www.screenr.com/EUy). The code is as follows:

```
- (void)swipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer direction:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection)direction
{
    if (recognizer && recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        // Get the table view cell where the swipe occured
        CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
        MyCell* cell = (MyCell *) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];

        //removing the options view at the other cell before adding a new one

        if (global != nil && global.row != indexPath.row){
            [sideSwipeView removeFromSuperview];
            sideSwipeView = nil;
        }

        //options already exist, we need to remove it
        if (sideSwipeView != nil){
            [sideSwipeView removeFromSuperview];
            sideSwipeView = nil;
            slide = NO;
        } else {
            //options do not exist and therefore we need to add it
            NSArray * buttonData = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mark Read", @"title", @"mark.png", @"image", nil],
                                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Track", @"title", @"play.png", @"image", nil],
                                     nil] retain];

            NSMutableArray * buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:buttonData.count];
            sideSwipeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height-25, 320, 25)];
            [sideSwipeView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
            [sideSwipeView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"dotted-pattern.png"]]];
            [sideSwipeView setTag:-10];

            CGFloat leftEdge = BUTTON_LEFT_MARGIN;
            for (NSDictionary* buttonInfo in buttonData)
            {
                if (!([[buttonInfo objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:@"Mark Read"] && [[[topics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] unread] intValue] == 0))
                {

                    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

                    button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

                    UIImage* buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[buttonInfo objectForKey:@"image"]];
                    if ([[topics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] tracked] && [[buttonInfo objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:@"Track"]){
                        buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"];
                        [button setSelected:YES];
                    } else {
                        [button setSelected:NO];
                    }
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(leftEdge, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

                    UIImage* grayImage = [self imageFilledWith:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0] using:buttonImage];
                    [button setImage:grayImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                    if ([[buttonInfo objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:@"Mark Read"]){
                        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(markRead:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    } else if ([[buttonInfo objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:@"Track"]){
                        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(track:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    }
                    [button setTag:indexPath.row];
                    [buttons addObject:button];

                    [sideSwipeView addSubview:button];

                    leftEdge = leftEdge + buttonImage.size.width + BUTTON_SPACING;
                }
            }

            [cell.contentView addSubview:sideSwipeView];
            [sideSwipeView release];
            global = indexPath;
            slide = YES;

        }
        [self.tableView endUpdates]; 
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];        

    }
}
```

However, I am not confident that the code is memory correct (i.e: ther's no memory leak and I am not misusing anything). I am mostly not confident in the **sideSwipeView** alloc, dealloc, and setting it up to nil. I think the others are fine. Can someone give me any pointers?

Profiler result:

[image]

Comment: Before poring over your code, have you run the analyzer? In Xcode 4 it's under the Product menu, "Analyze". In Xcode 3 I believe it's in the Build menu as "Build and Analyze". If that's clear and you're still concerned then asking here makes sense, but if you haven't run it I'd like to suggest it first so you can resolve anything it finds.

Comment: I did run a profiler, the image is shown above.. not sure if it has to do with sideSwipeView or not..seems like it has to do with the buttons

Comment: It looks like you need to release the objects on line 229/234. Hard to say exactly what they are without line numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of thumb when dealing with memory management in Objective-C is that you should explicitly release objects that you are: (1) allocating (alloc), (2) cloning (copy), or newing up (new, which is a combination of alloc/init).

With that knowledge, go over your code, look for places where you're doing the above, and make sure you're releasing them once you're done with them. One example of an object that you're not releasing is `buttons`.

You should also read up on how objects are retained. For example, when you remove a view from a superview, if it is not retained anywhere else, it'll be released. You don't need to explicitly set the value to nil.

Comment: I have actually kept that in mind when writing my code..., but somehow I am still not sure

Comment: At first glance, it doesn't look like you're releasing the buttons array. You should also do a build and analyze like Matthew Frederick recommended in his comment. That should generate warnings if the analyzer comes across anything that it suspects hasn't been released and will cause a memory leak.

Comment: I agree with @cs, you are retaining the buttonData array, but it never gets released anywhere. If you are only planning to use the buttonData array in this scope then there is no need to retain it.

Answer (score 0):

The clang static analyzer is good for finding simple leaks but it won't catch them all. I've found that it's worth profiling your code and simply watching the allocations. Perform simple functions in your application and if you see things increasing, and not reducing as expected, a leak is the likely cause. Another indicator can be unexpected errors and crashes coming from classes you would expect to have been deallocated. Debug logging can also pick things up if you see messages coming from classes that should have cleared.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray * buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:buttonData.count];
```

seems like you have not released, the space you have allocated in it, this may cause leak,
use,

```
[button release];
button=nil;
```

I think, you should check and make sure that you have released  **button** in following scope:

```
else{
        //options do not exist and therefore we need to add it
        NSArray * buttonData = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mark Read", @"title", @"mark.png", @"image", nil],
                                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Track", @"title", @"play.png", @"image", nil],
                                 nil] retain];

        NSMutableArray * buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:buttonData.count];
        sideSwipeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height-25, 320, 25)];
        [sideSwipeView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
        [sideSwipeView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"dotted-pattern.png"]]];
        [sideSwipeView setTag:-10];

        CGFloat leftEdge = BUTTON_LEFT_MARGIN;
        for (NSDictionary* buttonInfo in buttonData)
        {
            if (!([[buttonInfo objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:@"Mark Read"] && [[[topics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] unread] intValue] == 0))
            {

                UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

                button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

                UIImage* buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[buttonInfo objectForKey:@"image"]];
                if ([[topics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] tracked] && [[buttonInfo objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:@"Track"]){
                    buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"];
                    [button setSelected:YES];
                } else {
                    [button setSelected:NO];
                }
                button.frame = CGRectMake(leftEdge, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

                UIImage* grayImage = [self imageFilledWith:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0] using:buttonImage];
                [button setImage:grayImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                if ([[buttonInfo objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:@"Mark Read"]){
                    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(markRead:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                } else if ([[buttonInfo objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:@"Track"]){
                    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(track:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                }
                [button setTag:indexPath.row];
                [buttons addObject:button];

                [sideSwipeView addSubview:button];

                leftEdge = leftEdge + buttonImage.size.width + BUTTON_SPACING;
            }
        }

        [cell.contentView addSubview:sideSwipeView];
        [sideSwipeView release];
        global = indexPath;
        slide = YES;

    }
```

Comment: You're sending the release message to nil and leaking the button object. You need to release first and then set the pointer to nil.